# Why does pasting a transparent image on a GIF distort it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, animated-gif

I have an transparent image with RGBA code `(0, 0, 0, 0)`, on which I added some pictures and text. Now, I am trying to paste that on a GIF image, but it is completely ruining it.

Here is my transparent image:

[image: Transparent]

Here is my GIF:

[image: Gif]

And, this is what I get:

[image: final]

This is my code:

```
from PIL import ImageSequence
im = Image.open('newav.gif')
frames = []
for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(im):
    frame = frame.copy()
    frame.paste(card, (0, 0), card)
    frames.append(frame)
frames[0].save('rank_card_gif.gif', save_all=True, append_images=frames[1:], loop=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining existent, animated GIFs with static PNGs having transparency doesn't work that easily – at least solely using Pillow. Your [GIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF) can only store upto 256 different colors using some color palette, thus has [mode](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#modes) `P` (or `PA`), when opened using Pillow. Now, your PNG probably has a lot of more colors. When pasting the PNG onto the GIF, the color palette of the GIF is used to convert some of the PNG's colors, which gives unexpected or unwanted results, cf. your output.

My idea would be, since you're already iterating each frame:

1. Convert the frame to `RGB`, to get the "explicit" colors from the palette.
2. Convert the frame to some NumPy array, and manually [alpha blend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) the frame and the PNG using its alpha channel.
3. Convert the resulting frame back a Pillow `Image` object.

Thus, all frames are stored as `RGB`, all colors are the same for all frames. So, when now saving a new GIF, the new color palette is determined from this set of images.

Here's my code for the described procedure:

```py
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence
import numpy as np

# Read gif using Pillow
gif = Image.open('gif.gif')

# Read png using OpenCV
pngg = cv2.imread('png.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# Extract alpha channel, repeat for later alpha blending
alpha = np.repeat(pngg[..., 3, np.newaxis], 3, axis=2) / 255

frames = []
for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(gif):
    frame = frame.copy()

    # Convert frame to RGB
    frame = frame.convert('RGB')

    # Convert frame to NumPy array; convert RGB to BGR for OpenCV
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(np.asarray(frame), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

    # Manual alpha blending
    frame = np.uint8(pngg[..., :3] * alpha + frame * (1 - alpha))

    # Convert BGR to RGB for Pillow; convert frame to Image object
    frame = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))

    frames.append(frame)
frames[0].save('output.gif', append_images=frames[1:], save_all=True,
               loop=0, duration=gif.info['duration'])
```

And, this is the result:

[image]

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
NumPy:         1.20.1
OpenCV:        4.5.1
Pillow:        8.1.0
----------------------------------------
```